# How to get value from access database row by row after each click on button?

Tags: c#

I want to get questions one by one by clicking on button from access database table. Each question is one single row, want to get every next question by clicking on *"next"* button from every next row. I have made this code but this directly shows last question in the table of last row. Please do help me in this. As this is related to my final year project of BS computer science.

This is my code:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= E:\\sampleDb.accdb");
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand ("select Questions from sampletable", con);
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int count = dr.FieldCount;
while (dr.Read())
{                   
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
          label1.Text = dr.GetValue(i).ToString();
     }                   
}

dr.Close();
con.Close();
```

Comment: It scares me a little that they aren't teaching about the `using` keyword in the final year of a BS degree...  Anyway, is the assignment requiring a `DataReader`?  If not, have you considered a `DataTable` and then looping through the rows instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have made this code but this directly shows last question in the
>   table of last row.

Why shouldn't it? Becuase you select one column in your query (`Questions`) but you try to access all column values from `i` to `count`. That's pointless.

Let's say you have `10` rows that returns on your query. `10` rows with `1` column. So your `count` variable will be `10`. So your `while` statement will execute your `for` loop `10` times.

But in your `for` loop, when `i` will be `1`, `GetValue(1)` will try to look second column value of current row but wait a minute..! **THERE IS NO SECOND COLUMN IN YOUR QUERY!** Because you defined only one column your query.

That's your first problem.

Second problem is, you using `Label` control, which simply displays a text. With this code it displays only the last question becuase when this code finish, your code only shows the last cell of your `Questions` column. Becuase in every loop, your `label1.Text` will change. So basicly, at the end your code, it will show the last question at all.

If you try to show all your questions, choose different asp.net control instead of `Label`.

I believe this explanation is better for you than just writing some code.